# How to query an individual collector?

Tags: opentsdb

I have number of tcollector collectors which report to OpenTSDB. I want to investigate one specific collector, namely procstats.py. I would like to see what it outputs. How do I do that? Executing the collector directly with python unfortunately fails with:

```
[root]# python procstats.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "procstats.py", line 23, in <module>
    from collectors.lib import utils
ImportError: No module named collectors.lib
```

Answer (score 1):

PYTHONPATH=.. python 0/procstats.py